# Kotlin - Getting 'return is not allowed here' error when attempting to return to enclosing function from lambda

Tags: kotlin

Attempting to return to an enclosing function (`foo`) from a lambda shows error `return is not allowed here`.

What's happening here? Am I doing something wrong?

```
fun bar( baz: () -> Unit ) {

    // Empty function
}

fun foo() : Unit? {

    return null // this works fine

    bar {

        return null // shows error 'return is not allowed here'
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've also tried:

```
...

bar {

    return@bar null
}

...
```

But this gives the error `Null can not be a value of a non-null type Unit`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Kotlin there is the rule - `return` returns from `fun` always. One may use `return@<label/function name>` to return from function or lambdas.

Next, there comes `inline fun`. Inline functions are not real functions, they are inlined into the call site, thus, it is possible to do a return from inside a lambda that is a parameter to such function (there are many examples of that in the standard library)

To summarize:

```
inline fun bar(a: () -> Unit) { a() }
fun buz() : Int {
  bar { return 42 } /// such return is only possible to inline fun
  return 10
}
val x = buz() /// will be 42
```

```
bar { if (something) return@bar }
```

here we return from the lambda, not from a function.

Answer (score 3):

`return` statement is not allowed inside a lambda. If you want to return from a lambda, you should use label.

```
bar {
    return@bar 
}
```

Or you can use [inline](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) modifier for `bar` function.

Comment: Tried it already, it gives `Null can not be a value of a non-null type Unit`

Comment: Yes, that's right because result will be returned to `baz` function. And return type of `baz` is `Unit`.

Comment: I want to return to the **enclosing function**, that's `foo`.

Comment: That would be a [non-local return](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns), which you can only perform in an inline function.

Comment: @zsmb13 Thanks, I completely missed `(Note that such non-local returns are supported only for lambda expressions passed to inline functions.)` in https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html

Answer (score 2):

We all know the facts in kotlin specs. but the reason behind it is not trivial at all.

The problem is: Why in kotlin, return is not allowed in a lambda by default?

Though this is an old question, it is still important for me to explain the possible reasons.

On the first glance, anonymous functions and lambdas behave pretty much the same: a nameless function thing. However with the keyword `fun`, `return` is allowed in the function body but without `fun` (in lambda) it is not allowed! Aren't they all "functions"?

Lambda is indeed a function, but literally it is more like a platonic "expression", it will eventually represent an Object by its own design intention, thus an return is not really needed.

Moreover, `return` in lambda can be ambiguous due to "function inline" and "non-local return" feature/syntax-sugar. If the lambda is inlined, the return is "non-local" by its lexical context, meaning it terminates and returns from the caller function. But when it is not inlined and we allow return here, what behavior do we expect? It's contradictory and unintuitive.

That's why offering an label is mandatory to use return in lambda without inline. Of course we can use labeled-return anywhere but it only adds boilerplate work.

Comment: the "Lambda will eventually represent an Object by its own design intention" helped to clear it for me

Answer (score 2):

Tested. This works for me.

```kotlin
val lambdaFunc: () -> Unit = MyLabel@{ ->
    if (!somethingFail()) {
        return@MyLabel
    }
    
    // Do another things
}
```

Hope this help someone.

Comment: Thank you! For other readers the trick is to declare your own label. It seems that for some lambda used in top level declaration, Kotlin cannot automatically infer or create a label for this lambda, for this reason it's seems necessary to declare one (e.g. `MyLabel`) and use it on the `return` statement (e.g. `return@MyLabel`).